# Python bottle + postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, bottle

I have a problem. I installed pgadmin3. Created a base with encoding UTF-8. Create a file index.py:

```
# -*- coding utf-8 -*-

from bottle import route, run, template, request, install
from bottle_pgsql import PgSQLPlugin

install(PgSQLPlugin('dbname=test, user=postgres password=111'))

@route('/hello')
def hello(db):
    c = db.execute('''SELECT gorod FROM gorod''')
    result = c.fetchone()
    return template('hello', rows=result)

run (host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Next i created tpl-file hello.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Статистика</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{rows}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i go to the page http: // localhost: 8080 / hello error:

```
Critical error while processing request: /hello

Error:

UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle\n    return route.call(**args)\n  File "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper\n    rv = callback(*a, **ka)\n  File "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test\\bottle_pgsql.py", line 83, in wrapper\n    con = psycopg2.connect(dsn)\n  File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\psycopg2\\__init__.py", line 164, in connect\n    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)\nOperationalError: \xc2\xc0\xc6\xcd\xce:  \xe1\xe0\xe7\xe0 \xe4\xe0\xed\xed\xfb\xf5 "test," \xed\xe5 \xf1\xf3\xf9\xe5\xf1\xf2\xe2\xf3\xe5\xf2\n\n', 512, 513, 'invalid continuation byte')
Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 954, in wsgi
    out = self._cast(self._handle(environ))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 907, in _cast
    out = self.error_handler.get(out.status_code, self.default_error_handler)(out)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 842, in default_error_handler
    return tob(template(ERROR_PAGE_TEMPLATE, e=res))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 3595, in template
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 3399, in render
    self.execute(stdout, env)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 3386, in execute
    eval(self.co, env)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 3337, in <lambda>
    self._escape = lambda x: escape_func(touni(x, enc))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\bottle.py", line 123, in touni
    return s.decode(enc, err) if isinstance(s, bytes) else unicode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 512: invalid continuation byte
```

Can you help me!
Sorry for my bad english ;)
Thanks

Comment: Could you check the encoding of hello.tpl file? I guess it's saved in cp-1251 instead of utf-8.

Comment: Save all file with UTF-8 encoding, but is't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to encode your template file in UTF-8 ?

With iconv for example :

```
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 "hello.tpl" -o "hello.tpl"
```

*Edit* : you can use [iconv for windows here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)

Comment: Is it for Linux OS? But I am use Windows 7 )

Comment: You can use [Iconv for windows from gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)